# ¿Como convertir un datetime a date con formato (´d-m-y') haciendo un select con query builder en laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente código quiero retornar la fecha que se encuentra en mi base de datos `mysql` en formato datetime. ¿Como lo convierto a date y darle formato desde un `select` en query builder con `laravel`?.

```
public function fecha(){
$fechas= DB::table('detail_books')->select('DATE_FORMAT('fechallegada','%d-%m-%Y')')->get();
return view("factura",compact('fechas'));
}
```

Sin embargo obtengo error en el select.

Saludos

Comment: Si te da un error, procura siempre indicarlo. Hace más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: FatalErrorException in roomsController.php line 266:
syntax error, unexpected 'detail_books' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error de sintaxis**

Prueba con esto:

```
 public function fecha(){
    $fechas= DB::table('detail_books')->select("DATE_FORMAT(fechallegada,'%d-%m-%Y')")->get();
    return view("factura",compact('fechas'));
  }
```

Al usar la combinación de comillas simples en la siguiente sentencia está generando el error.

```
'DATE_FORMAT('fechallegada','%d-%m-%Y')'
```

Debes probar reemplezando por:

```
"DATE_FORMAT(fechallegada,'%d-%m-%Y') as fechallegada"
```

**Actualización**

Debes usar `selectRaw` para formatear desde la consulta. El código debe quedar como sigue:

```
public function fecha(){ 
$fechas= DB::table('detail_books')->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(fechallegada,'%d-%m-%Y')")->get(); 
return view("factura",compact('fechas')); 
}
```

Comment: Me muestra el siguiente errorQueryException in Connection.php line 666:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT('detail_books.fechallegada','%d-%m-%Y')' in 'field list' (SQL: select `detail_books`

Comment: prueba quitando la comilla simple de **'fechallegada'** que quede así  `"DATE_FORMAT(fechallegada,'%d-%m-%Y')"`

Comment: continua el error QueryException in Connection.php line 666:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(detail_books.fechallegada,'%d-%m-%Y')'

Comment: Ahora actualice la respuesta.

Comment: mismo error sigue dando

Comment: ¿probaste con **DB::raw()**? debes usar también el **as fechallegada**

Comment: eso no funciona con join

Comment: Gracias la solucion a como me indiscastes estaba en usar SelectRaw y una sola comilla doble con inicio y fin.